# Update array in react using useState

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter, react-hooks, use-state

hey there I am trying to remove the object and set a new data but however each time I try it calls back the previous state. for example remove for emma  return ([ {name:"red"},{name:"reeed"} ], then a remove for reed should return ([ {name:"red"} ] however it returns ([ {name:"red"},{name:"emma"}]. Thanks in advance

```
const [test1, setTest] = useState([ {name:"red"},{name:"reeed"},{name:"emma"}]);

const deleteFunction= (name) => { 
        setTest([...test1.filter(item => item.name !==  name)]);       
    };
```

Comment: is this the exact code? you can't name a variable `delete` since it's a reserved word in JS

Comment: no its not, sorry my bad!

Comment: how are you checking that the state has changed or not? can you show more code?

Comment: OOH wait nvrm I figured but thank you!

Comment: Yeah it does! thank you!

Answer (score -1):

**Solution :**

setTest((prevState) => (prevState.filter(item => item.name !==  name)));